# Can't recognize the kanji

Tags: kanji, handwriting

[image]

Can anyone tell what that kanji is? The left part looks a bit like 禽 but trying to use its radicals for searching isn't giving me anything close to resembling the one in the image.

Comment: I thought it might be that but the right part looked like it had the radical 个 so at first I thought that maybe it was something else.

Comment: らめー is like だめー with the speaker having something in his/her mouth. It's either a hentai or a comedy scene

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's 離.

> 「[離]{はな}してー」
>   "Let go of me. / Let me go."

(But I have no idea what 「らめー」 means)

Comment: That one is just more childish version of 「だめー」,the person is trying to escape after breaking something while other people are holding her down while they wait for the police to arrive.

Comment: あぁ、「だめ～」("No~!")って言ってたのね・・ぜんぜん気づかんかった（笑）